# How do I find the index of an item in an array of [Any]()?

Tags: ios, swift

```
var items = [Any]()
```

I want to find the index of an object `User` (in this case, a class).

`items.indexOf(myUserInstance)` throws an error (Cannot convert value of type 'User' to expected argument type '@noescape(Any) throws -> Bool)

`items.indexOf(myUserInstance as? Any)` throws an error too.

Is there a simple extension that will allow me to use `indexOf`? Right now, I'm looping every item, type-casting, and checking if the ID property equals...

Comment: why don't you make array of User like `var items = [User]()`

Comment: Because I want the array to be [Any]() . Sometimes, I put ```User``` in it, sometimes I put structs in it, etc.

Comment: ```[AnyObjects]()``` don't allow me to append structs inside.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33436331/swift-cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-noescape-while-call-indexof-after-filte

Comment: @originaluser2 I'm not sure what that is - so probably not.  It's just a normal class.

Comment: @TIMEX So how are you hoping to compare two `User` instances? Or are you just looking for pointer equality? – Nevermind, just seen your comment below

Answer (score 1):

can try something like

```
    items.indexOf { x in
        if let u = x as? User {
            if(u === user){
               return true;
            }
        }

        return false
    }
```

might be a more elegant way of writing this, but thats all i got so far

Comment: I'd like to check for the exact instance. Doesn't this just check for the type?

Comment: oh i made a mistake before, you can try my updated method

Comment: I think this would work, but would it not be `if(u === user){` to be sure that it's the same object instance?

Comment: @AndyHeard ye i guess, probably more correct in this case

Comment: Does this run in linear time?

Comment: @TIMEX im not sure, but i think it would since the block should be called on each element exactly once and doesnt need to access any other elements when assessing each one

Answer (score 0):

How about `items.indexOf { $0 as? User === user }` ?

This will return an optional containing either the first index the `User` object is within the array, or `nil` (`.None`) if the user is not within the collection.

If your `User` class is deriver from `NSObject` and it overrides the `isEqual:` method, then you can use the `==` operator instead of `===` to also find objects that are equal in contents; `==` will call the `isEqual:` method behind the scenes instead of comparing the pointers, as oposed to `===`.

Comment: I'm trying to match it with an exact instance . Does this match it to the instance or class?

Comment: @TIMEX sorry I didn't caught that, I though you want to find the first `User` object in the container. I updated my answer to reflect your query.

Answer (score -1):

// we can retrive index like this

```
(items as! NSArray).indexOfObject(user)
```

Comment: That doesn't return an optional.  How can I make it return nil if the item is not inside?

Comment: then use (items as! NSArray).containsObject(user)

Comment: it return Bool value

Comment: Forced unwraps are rarely a good idea, and should be avoided.